# VSCode unable to debug. [Errno2] No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a print("hello") to whatever if it is going to work or not on VSCode. It doesn't.

As I mentioned in the header, when I debug the current .py file it throws an error below;

[image]

And then debugger throws time out error.

I've checked the directories and only one of them doesn't exist.
It is the: "**c:\Users\AOVARE.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher**".

But this directory does show it has this folder: "**C:\Users\AOVAİRE.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher**"

I guess you all have seen the difference but still, I have to highlight;
It is supposed to be "**AOVAİRE**" not "**AOVARE**".

The same problem occurs on other projects as well. C++/C and so on.
When I tried to debug something it throws this error with the same directory(AOVARE).

(Edit): I also have a laptop. Tested on that and everything works correctly.

Is there a way that I can change this directory to the correct one?
Or are there any other solutions?